# Eclipse - how to use code folding only for specific code

Tags: eclipse, code-folding

I am working with eclipse and i got some classes which are huge. Due to this it is not nice to search in those for something. Is there a possibility to only hide/show specific code? I saw that eclipse has some function called code folding, but im not sure if this is what i am searching for

Im searching for something like a tag, which i add at the beginning and at the end of the code which i want to be fold-able. like this for example

```
public class MyClass{

  private int someVar;
  private int someVar2;
  <foldingBlock1>
  private int someVar3;
  private int someVar4;
  </foldingBlock1>
  private int someVar5;

}
```

So in this example the code between 'foldingBlock1' and '/foldingblock1' is fold-able and can be folded so it would look like this

```
public class MyClass{

  private int someVar;
  private int someVar2;
  <foldingBlock1>
  private int someVar5;

}
```

Thanks,
Baschdi

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way i Know. To hide/show some method within a class.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not really what i was searching for. Like i said, im searching for a way to hide/show a custom defined area of code